# Mysql Select value then update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Basically what I'm trying to do is get a turn id out of a table, but after the value is returned it needs to be incremented by 1. After 10 increments, it resets to 0;

So I want do do something similar to this but I can't seem to get it working:

```
UPDATE `gan` SET `turn` = (SELECT `turn` FROM `gan` WHERE `gan_id`='$gan_id') + 1
```

I also haven't figured out how to check if the value is 10 to reset it to 0;

So what I need to happen, in my php mysql query, the current turn be returned for the gan_id i pass in and increment it after the value has been returned.

I've tried running two separate queries but I'm running into issue where multiple users are getting the same turn.

Comment: If you want to prevent race conditions, lock the table when updating.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT turn FROM gan WHERE gan_id = $gan_id FOR UPDATE");
$turn = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$someNewVal = $turn == 10 ? 0 : $turn + 1;
$resUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE gan SET turn = $someNewVal WHERE gan_id = $gan_id");
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1");
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

No? You need select FOR UPDATE if you wanna handle concurrency.

Comment: The Locking of Tables Method worked. I just wonder at what performance cost. I'm going to try the Transaction method you posted No Way. See if that's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE `gan` SET `turn` =(SELECT MAX(`turn`) FROM `gan` WHERE `gan_id`='$gan_id')+ 1)
```

This will increment the value.

To check the value and reset it to 0, You have to lock the table and then perform your task

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CASE` expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```sql
UPDATE gan
SET    turn = CASE turn WHEN 10 THEN 0 ELSE turn + 1 END
WHERE  gan_id = ?
```

Or the [`IF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```sql
UPDATE gan SET turn = IF(turn<10, turn+1, 0) WHERE gan_id = ?
```